# Is it possible to reduce a Java Stream<T> to a new Stream<T> solely with the reduce function

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to reduce a stream of objects to a new stream of the same object type by removing duplicates based on specific properties and increment the value for those properties. In the animal example below I would be matching the typeOfAnimal then breed and summing the age in the new animal. So a list of:

```
[
  {"typeOfAnimal": "dog", "breed": "Labrador", "age": 5},
  {"typeOfAnimal": "dog", "breed": "Labrador", "age": 3},
  {"typeOfAnimal": "dog", "breed": "Poodle", "age": 7},
  {"typeOfAnimal": "cat", "breed": "Bengal", "age": 1}
]
```

The result should look like this:

```
[
  {"typeOfAnimal": "dog", "breed": "Labrador", "age": 8},
  {"typeOfAnimal": "dog", "breed": "Poodle", "age": 7},
  {"typeOfAnimal": "cat", "breed": "Bengal", "age": 1}
]
```

So far to achieve this result I have had to use the *groupingBy* and *reducing* collectors because I have been unable to write this as a single *reducer* operator. Here is my working example:

```
Stream<Animal> results = animals
    .stream()
    .collect(
        groupingBy(Animal::getTypeOfAnimal,
            groupingBy(Animal::getBreed,
                reducing(
                    new Animal().withAge(0),
                    (a,c) -> new Animal()
                        .withTypeOfAnimal(c.getTypeOfAnimal())
                        .withBreed(c.getBreed())
                        .withAge(c.getAge() + a.getAge())))))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(a -> a.values().stream());
```

Does the *reduce* operator allow for this or do I need to stick with the current example? My preference for a single reducer function is because my actual code has more levels and therefore more *groupingBy* statements

Comment: Stick with your current way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are now grouping by a single property each time.

But you could also group by the desiring properties at once:

First, create a `GroupingKey` record:

```java
public static record GroupingKey(String type, String breed) {
    public static GroupingKey of(Animal animal) {
        return new GroupingKey(animal.getTypeOfAnimal(), animal.getBreed());
    }
}
```

This helps us to define on which fields the animal is grouped.

Then we define a `merge` method, which helps to merge two animals.

```java
private static Animal merge(Animal a, Animal b) {
    int age = (a != null ? a.getAge() : 0);
    return new Animal(b.getTypeOfAnimal(), b.getBreed(), age + b.getAge());
}
```

And then you could just reduce once:

```java
Map<GroupingKey, Animal> map = animals.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(GroupingKey::of, reducing(null, t -> merge(t))));
```

Then by calling `values()`, you could retrieve a `Collection` with all `Animal`s.

Comment: I'm taking it from this answer that the answer to my question is **No**, btw, here's a neater way of doing it ;-) which works perfectly thanks, and it is much more readable.

Comment: @APW The answer is indeed "no", as far as I know. I'm glad this alternative solution helped you!